# Extract Google Sheet Comments from cell to new Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, comments, google-sheets-api

I have a inventory list with Google Sheet and used Comments as record for transaction.
However, it's reaching the limit and i can't add more.
Is that possible to make the script run automatically with all comments it has now and delete the comment once it's export?
Then I could use the new sheet with v-lookup to generate the transaction record for each shipment

I did some research and saw below App Script could export the comments from the a Sheet to another one.
I've tried but it only showing 20 comments and it's on the inventory list, not the sheet i want

Below is the link for the inventory file.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ssb9zmlg4cixqe7fUcC7Uma1mizI7R3Y_ZETCcq4m-E/edit#gid=436319921

```
    function listComments() {
      // Change docId into your document's ID
      // See below on how to
      var docId = '1Ssb9zmlg4cixqe7fUcC7Uma1mizI7R3Y_ZETCcq4m-E'; 
      var comments = Drive.Comments.list(docId);
      var hList = [], cList = [];

      // Get list of comments
      if (comments.items && comments.items.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < comments.items.length; i++) {
          var comment = comments.items[i]; 
          // add comment and highlight to array's first element 
          hList.unshift([comment.context.value]);
          cList.unshift([comment.content]);
        }
        // Set values to A and B
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
        sheet.getRange("A1:A" + hList.length).setValues(hList);
        sheet.getRange("B1:B" + cList.length).setValues(cList);
      }
    }
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Your provided Spreadsheet is your sample input situation? If my understanding is correct, can you provide the sample output situation you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Hi yes that's the sample input situation and the output situation as below link  
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AHXHsecP5lg2XuONCCLUwH_W2sNUi_bNnt-TnRx_E3Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, for example, it seems that about the values of `2241` and `2446` in the cells "A1" and "A3", these values cannot be found in your provided Spreadsheet in your question. And, it seems that in your Spreadsheet, 4 sheets exist. Do you want to retrieve all comments from all sheets? And, you want to also retrieve the deleted comments? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Comment that i want to pull is from Sheet "Inventory", 2241 and 2446 are in cells AC2, AD2 and AC3, AD3 which i use those comments as inventory in and out record.
I want to retrieve comments from all sheets
Yes I want to see if the comments could be delete with the script once it's done retrieve so it' won't take up more "Comment Limit"
Sheet Inventory: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ssb9zmlg4cixqe7fUcC7Uma1mizI7R3Y_ZETCcq4m-E/edit#gid=436319921
Output Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AHXHsecP5lg2XuONCCLUwH_W2sNUi_bNnt-TnRx_E3Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I check your provided Spreadsheet, the object including `BL# 6181 08/17/21\nLot# 1798 77cs\nLot# 2241 7cs\n\t-BY Warehouse` has no property of `context`. So, unfortunately, the value of `2241` cannot be retrieved from `comment.context.value`. I apologize for this. In this case, what do you want to do?

Comment: So can it be done with only comments retrieved and delete afterward? I've updated the output comment sheet for the result i want

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your following reply,

> So can it be done with only comments retrieved and delete afterward? I've updated the output comment sheet for the result i want

In this case, how about the following sample scripts?

**In these samples, Drive API is used. So, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.**

#### Sample script 1:

In this sample, the comment is retrieved by "Method: comments.list" of Drive API. In the current stage, the cell coordinates of each comment cannot be identified. So, in this case, all comments are retrieved from all sheets in a Google Spreadsheet.

```js
function listComments1() {
  var docId = '1Ssb9zmlg4cixqe7fUcC7Uma1mizI7R3Y_ZETCcq4m-E';

  var res = [];
  var pageToken = "";
  do {
    var comments = Drive.Comments.list(docId, { includeDeleted: false, maxResults: 100, fields: "nextPageToken,items(content,context(value))", pageToken });
    res = [...res, ...comments.items.map(e => [e.content || null])];
    pageToken = comments.nextPageToken;
    console.log({ pageToken, len: comments.items.length, resLen: res.length });
  } while (pageToken);
  if (res.length == 0) return;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, res.length).setValues(res);
}
```

- When this script is run, the comments are retrieved from all sheets and the retrieved comments are put into column "A" of the active sheet.

#### Sample script 2:

In this sample, the comment is retrieved by "DocsServiceApp" of my Google Apps Script library. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/DocsServiceApp) When this library is used, the comments can be retrieved from the specific sheet.

Before you use this script, please install this library "DocsServiceApp". You can see how to install it at [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/DocsServiceApp#how-to-install).

```js
function listComments2() {
  var docId = '1Ssb9zmlg4cixqe7fUcC7Uma1mizI7R3Y_ZETCcq4m-E';

  const obj = DocsServiceApp.openBySpreadsheetId(docId).getSheetByName("Current").getComments();
  const res = obj.reduce((ar, { comment }) => {
    if (comment.length > 0) {
      ar = [...ar, ...comment.map(c => [c.comment.trim().replace("----", "").trim()])];
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (res.length == 0) return;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, res.length).setValues(res);
}
```

- When this script is run, the comments are retrieved from the specific sheet and the retrieved comments are put into column "A" of the active sheet.

#### References:

- [Method: comments.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/comments/list)
- [DocsServiceApp (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/DocsServiceApp)

Comment: I've tried it and it works~~~ Thanks a lot
Just couple more question, i've used the method 1 with comments.list, will it retrieve automcally?
Also if it will remove the old comments if i remove from the "Current " sheet?

Comment: @Charles Chan About `I've tried it and it works`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @Charles Chan About your new questions, I answered them as follows. About `i've used the method 1 with comments.list, will it retrieve automcally?`, it's no. About `Also if it will remove the old comments if i remove from the "Current " sheet?`, it's no. If you want new solutions of your new 2 questions, please post it as a new question. By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. Because your new questions are different from your this question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new questions, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?