# override Google Apps script stopping exporting comments when count max>20

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, extract, google-docs

The following script works great for creating a new tab in a sheet and populating that tab with comment data from a gdoc or a gsheet, but it only works for the first 20 comments in a file. Most of my files have more than 20 comments.

How do I overcome this limitation?

Note the logger line in the code that returns the number of comments in the file. This helped me learn that the script can't even count more than 20 comments. For example, my test file has 53 comments in it, but the logger counts 20. So, it's not that it sees all comments but can only extract data from the first 20——it seems not to see the last 33 comments at all.

```
function ExtractComments() {
//Important: For this to work, you must first go to the Services menu on the left and add Drive API v2 (it won't work with other versions). References are at the bottom of the script.

// Get spreadsheet and sheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
// Get file Id (user enters the ID in B4 of the active sheet and this grabs it from there)
    var fileID = sheet.getRange(4, 2).getValue();
    Logger.log('File Id is: ' + fileID);

// Get new tab name (user enters the name in B5 of the active sheet and this grabs it from there)
    var tabName = sheet.getRange(5, 2).getValue();
    Logger.log('Tab name is: ' + tabName);

// Create a new sheet and give it the tab name we grabbed above 
    var create = ss.insertSheet(tabName);
    Logger.log('New tab created');

// Get comments and ask Logger to show the number of comments it counts
    var comments = Drive.Comments.list(fileID).items;
        Logger.log('Number of comments:'+ comments.length);

// Define how comment data will appear in columns in new sheet: d = date, c = text in comment, n = author name, h = highlighted text    
    var dList = [], cList = [], nList = []; hList = []; // 2d array

// Execute extraction
    if (comments && comments.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {
          var comment = comments[i]; 
          dList.unshift([comment.author ? comment.author.displayName : '']);
          cList.unshift([comment.content]);
          nList.unshift([comment.context ? comment.context.value : '']);  
          hList.unshift([comment.createdDate ? new Date(comment.createdDate).toLocaleString() : '']);
    }
// Put comment data in new sheet
    var newSheet = ss.getSheetByName(tabName);
    if(newSheet !== null) {
      newSheet.getRange("A1:A" + dList.length).setValues(dList);
      newSheet.getRange("B1:B" + cList.length).setValues(cList);
      newSheet.getRange("C1:C" + nList.length).setValues(nList);
      newSheet.getRange("D1:D" + hList.length).setValues(hList);
    } else {
      Logger.log('Sheet "Comments" not found');
    }
  }
}
```

References

https://alicekeeler.com/2016/04/10/google-apps-script-create-new-tabs/

[Export Google Docs comments into Google Sheets, along with highlighted text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66103464/export-google-docs-comments-into-google-sheets-along-with-highlighted-text)

Comment: I believe you need to check the `nextPageToken` for more comments.

Comment: I thought that `the script can't even count more than 20 comments` depends on `pageSize` or `maxResults`. About `my test file has 53 comments in it`, first, you can try to use `pageSize: 100` for Drive API v3 or `maxResults: 100` for Drive API v2. When the number of comments is more than 100, please use `pageToken`. This thread might be an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/q/77108840 But, this answer uses Drive API v2. So, please be careful about the version number of the Drive API you are using.

Comment: @Tanaike: It works!!!! You are a genius. Thank you so, so much! 
For anyone else that falls on this thread, here's what to do: 
After the line "// Get comments and ask Logger to show the number of comments it counts," update the code as follows:
    var comments = Drive.Comments.list(fileID,{maxResults: 100}).items;

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Delete & flag obsolete comments. Please use question posts for questions & answer posts for answers. [ask] [Help] PS Yes or no questions are seldom useful & (since they ask for a yes or a no) are seldom asking what the asker actually wants answered.

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 0):

To override the max of 20, update these lines:

```
// Get comments and ask Logger to show the number of comments it counts
    var comments = Drive.Comments.list(fileID).items;
    Logger.log('Number of comments:'+ comments.length);
```

With these (it assigns a new max of 100):

```
// Get comments and ask Logger to show the number of comments it counts; FIX: The default max is 20 comments. maxResults increases that to 100
    var comments = Drive.Comments.list(fileID,{maxResults: 100}).items;
    Logger.log('Number of comments:'+ comments.length);
```